# How to keep changes I did in the Pod dependencies after I do cocoapods install again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I had to do some local changes to some frameworks I am using. However, I installed them with cocoapods. Is there any way to keep those changes when I do pod install again for new dependencies ?

Comment: I believe running `pod install` will not override already installed pods. Only `pod update` will do that (If there is an update available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ask question.

I am sorry to say this is not possible because when you have install or Update your pod then replace all file from new file.

**pod outdated:**

When you run pod outdated, CocoaPods will list all pods which have newer versions than the ones listed in the `Podfile.lock` (the versions currently installed for each pod). This means that if you run pod update PODNAME on those pods, they will be updated — as long as the new version still matches the restrictions like pod `'MyPod', '~>x.y'` set in your `Podfile`.

**pod update:**

When you run pod update PODNAME, CocoaPods will try to find an updated version of the pod PODNAME, without taking into account the version listed in `Podfile.lock`. It will update the pod to the latest version possible (as long as it matches the version restrictions in your `Podfile`).

If you run pod update with no pod name, CocoaPods will update every pod listed in your `Podfile` to the latest version possible.

You can also find reference from [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html).

Comment: There are now some exceptions in CocoaPods 1.1.1. For example the swift language build settings are now persisted even if you repeat pod install.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a folk on git, of that libraries in which you are doing changes localy, and use that  commit url instead of library name and version in pod file.

Whenever you are going to update lib, you will get your code.

This is solve your problem. :)